# Workbook_BeforeSave with every active workbook ActiveWorkbook

Tags: vba, excel

As I very often have to problem, that the tick vanishes in the settings: Calculate before save. (I don't know the exact term as my office version is in German).

That's why I tried to use VBA to solve the problem. I used the following code in my Excel file:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
    Cancel As Boolean)

If Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False Then
    If MsgBox("Caution! Should >calculatebeforesave< be activated?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Application.CalculateBeforeSave = True
    Else
    End If
Else
End If

End Sub
```

I put this into "Thisworkbook". But I would like this code to be ran in every workbook I work with (at least all these which allow for macros).

My suggestion was to write ActiveWorkbook_BeforeSave... instead of Workbook_BeforeSave and then put the code in a module in the PERSONAL Macro file. But this doesn't work.

Comment: all you need is application level event handler. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the Excel Applications events rather than workbook events to achieve this, such as in this [example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/213566)

In your PERSONAL workbook right click and insert a a Class Module (Class 1)

Add something similar to below to Class 1:

```
Public WithEvents appevent As Application

Private Sub appevent_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
 'Add what you would like to happen before a workbook closes

End Sub
```

Next open ThisWorksheet and add code along these lines (I think the PERSONAL workbook opens automatically when Excel starts):

```
Dim myobject As New Class1
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set myobject = Application
End Sub
```

Comment: Personal.xls/xlsb should open automatically when Excel starts, as long as you have it saved in the XLSTART folder :)